# Delete customers saved card on Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working on a project and implementing stripe. I've got most of it working without any issues but I'm following what the documentation says (or at least I believe I am) but I keep getting an error back from stripe when I attempt to delete a saved card from a customer.

I am using the following code:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($stripeCustomerId);
$customer->sources->retrieve($cardId)->delete();
```

I got this code from the API documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/delete.

The error I am getting back is:

> Invalid Stripe request received. Cards cannot be accessed without a
>   customer ID, account ID or recipient ID.

**UPDATE**

Below is a snippet of the customer response object showing the card id

```
10/03/2019 20:35:43 -29178-:INFO: D:\wamp64\www\API\classes\AccountManagement.php:1718: Stripe\Customer Object
(
    [id] => cus_EftaJCbcAIUaZW
    [object] => customer
    [account_balance] => 0
    [created] => 1552247956
    [currency] => gbp
    [default_source] => card_1ECYFHHvLpy648dRWUxb184n
```

And below is the CardId that I am using from the customer object to call `customer->sources->retrive(cardId)->delete();`

> 10/03/2019 20:35:43 -29178-:INFO:
>   D:\wamp64\www\API\classes\AccountManagement.php:1719: Got Card ID of
>   'card_1ECYFHHvLpy648dRWUxb184n'
>
> 10/03/2019 20:35:43 -29178-:INFO:
>   D:\wamp64\www\API\classes\AccountManagement.php:1763: Invalid Stripe
>   request received. Cards cannot be accessed without a customer ID,
>   account ID or recipient ID.

Comment: is `$stripeCustomerId` a valid customer id? and `$cardId` a valid card? also, what version of stripe's php SDK are you using?

Comment: @duck I've updated my question with the snippet of the customer object and the card ID I am using to delete the card. The Card ID from `default_source` is what I am using which match and it also matches what I see in the stripe dashboard. I'm using 6.30.2 for the PHP Stripe version

Comment: That's odd, I'm slightly stumped on this, just tried with same PHP SDK version and works about how you expect. `$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(["source"=>"tok_visa"]);
echo $customer; $card = $customer->sources->retrieve($customer->default_source); echo $card; echo $card->delete();`

Comment: Weird, I notice you fetched the card and then did a delete so I thought maybe that's the problem, but no, when I fetch the card, I can print the card object fine but then as soon as I call delete on it I get the error.

Comment: Weird for sure. It should work either way. Anything unusual in your Stripe error logs? https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?success=false

Comment: Na I had a look in there earlier but nothing about the card failing. I've emailed Stripe so I'll update here once figured out what the problem is

Comment: Just a clarification, have you checked in stripe panel with the card id you have mentioned and ensure that card is linked to the customer id you have mentioned her 'cus_EftaJCbcAIUaZW' ?

Comment: Yea I have done, I've printed out the both the customer object and the card Id I am using and they both match. I've reached out Stripe who are investigating as they're a bit confused as to why I'm getting that error